# SQL Server Escape Sequence while data import

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm importing data from a `.csv` file into SQL Server 2012 (Database --> Tasks --> Import)

I found this record in the `.csv` file

```
426264,Edappally\,Toll Junction\,Infront of Mosque\,,1900-01-01 06:25:00,1900-01-01 06:25:00,1139523,37,3248457
```

Actual view is I have to insert `"Edappally\,Toll Junction\,Infront of Mosque\"` in single column but my record is inserting `"Edappally\"` ,`"Toll Junction\"` ,`"Infront of Mosque\"` in different columns.

Can you please guys help me to insert "Edappally\,Toll Junction\,Infront of Mosque\" in single column?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server expects fields with commas to have quoted field identifiers (typically double quotes) if a field contains the delimiter, like `426264,"Edappally,Toll Junction,Infront of Mosque,",1900-01-01 06:25:00,...`.  Or maybe `426264,"Edappally\,Toll Junction\,Infront of Mosque\,",1900-01-01 06:25:00,...`.  I can't tell if you want the escaped sequence inserted or not.  The easiest solution would be to regenerate the data file with quoted field identifiers or a different delimiter.

If you're not able to do that, my suggestion would be to change the field delimiter in the file you already have.  Assuming every comma in the file is either a delimiter or appears like `\,`, you can make the change pretty easily.

First, pick a new delimiter.  The pipe character, `|`, or a tab are both good.  Let's say you choose pipe.

Next, make sure the pipe character isn't in the file anywhere.  There are many ways to do that.  A text editor is probably the easiest.

Then, search the file and replace every comma with a pipe.  This will replace your escaped commas, too, but we'll fix that next.

Finally, replace every instance of `\|` with `\,` (or just `,` if you don't need the escape in the inserted field).  This should revert all the escaped commas that we changed in the previous step.

Now when you import it into SQL Server, tell it you're using `|` instead of `,` for the field delimiter.